# How to simplify jQuery script for website with several navigation menus?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple website with at least a half dozen navigation bars that simply link to PDF files. The number of navigation bars keeps growing, but I don't want to have to keep adding the same line of code to make sure all other drop-downs are closed when another is clicked.

Is there a way to simplify the "else" component of this code, to remove classes expanded and open to all before adding the classes expanded and open to the one navigation bar that is clicked?

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav-lls-mobile").html($("#nav-lls-main").html());
        $("#nav-lls-trigger span").click(function(){
            if ($("nav#nav-lls-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
                $("nav#nav-lls-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $(this).removeClass("open"); 
            } else {
                $("nav#nav-lls-scorecard-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-lls-scorecard-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-lls-lineup-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-lls-lineup-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-lls-coordinator-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-lls-coordinator-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-llb-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-llb-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-llb-scorecard-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-llb-scorecard-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-llb-lineup-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-llb-lineup-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-general-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-general-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-coordinator-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
                $("#nav-coordinator-trigger span").removeClass("open");
                $("nav#nav-lls-mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
                $(this).addClass("open");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
               <div class="banner-label">
    Softball Scorecards
    </div>
    <div id="nav-lls-scorecard-trigger" class="nav-trigger-lls">
        <span>Softball Scorecards</span>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav-lls-scorecard-main" class="nav-main-lls">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./imports/SoftballScorecard1.pdf">Game 1 Scorecard</a></li>
            <li><a href="./imports/SoftballScorecard2.pdf">Game 2 Scorecard</a></li>
            <li><a href="./imports/SoftballScorecard3.pdf">Game 3 Scorecard</a></li>
            <li><a href="./imports/SoftballScorecard4.pdf">Game 4 Scorecard</a></li>
            <li><a href="./imports/SoftballScorecard5.pdf">Game 5 Scorecard</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="nav-lls-scorecard-mobile" class="nav-mobile-lls"></nav>
```

Mobile screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBKPs.png): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBKPs.png]
 Desktop screenshot: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJSS0.png): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJSS0.png]

Comment: maybe mark all those elements with separate class/name? so you can simplify selectors

Comment: can u share ur CSS or create a Fiddle?

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/501101/